# Macro to insert row to specified column range below the active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to modify this code, or if one could write me one which would be more efficient.

Not This formula works great, but I need the new row to insert only in column A to F.

The reason being, I have data/report table from H3 to K36 which needs to stay and cannot be modified with new rows.

```
Sub InsertRow()    
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then

        Dim numCopies As Long
        numCopies = 1

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To numCopies
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Next i

        ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numCopies, 0)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Resize(, 6).Insert Shift:=xlDown`

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Modify and try one of the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert ' <- Insert a row at row 1
        .Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Insert ' <- Insert 3 rows from 1
    End With

End Sub
```